# Title not been exported correctly

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm trying to export a simple plot like this one

```
myplot = 
 ListLogLogPlot[{{}, {}, {}}, PlotRange -> 10^{{1, 4}, {-10, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Blue, Orange},
  Frame -> True, Joined -> False,
  AspectRatio -> 0.65,
  FrameStyle -> 15, LabelStyle -> Directive[15, Black],
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["", Italic, 18], 
     Style["", 18]}, {Style["", 18], None}},
  Filling -> {4 -> {Top, Directive[Brown, Opacity[0.8]]}},
  ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[LineLegend[
      {Style["Case A", 12], Style["Case B", 12], 
       Style["Case C", 12]},
      LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}], 
        Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}], 
        Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}]},
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5, 
          Background -> White] &),
      LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}], {0.75, 0.15}]},
  PlotLabel -> 
   Text[Style[
     StringForm["Parameter X = `` and Parameter Y = ``", 1, 2], Black,
      17]]]
```

[image]

using the following line:

```
Export["Plot.png", myplot, ImageResolution -> 500];
```

Surprisingly, the PNG file has a problem with the tile:

[image]

that goes away if I remove the legend, which I need --of course:

[image]

What could be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: v13.1 on Win 11 work fine.

Comment: Thanks, @cvgmt. Mine is v12.0.0.0 on macOS Ventura 13.0.1

Comment: Yes, It also does not work on v11.3. But I found that the legend disapear when we using 13.1.

Comment: Do you need an empty plot with a title and a legend?

Comment: Thanks, @Syed. I’m not including the dataset for the sake of replicating the glitch

Comment: Does this change behavior: `ListLogLogPlot[{{1}, {1}, {1}},...`?

Comment: @Syed, the glitch occurs with/without showing the data. I ended up using a newer Mathematica version and that miraculously worked

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modify [**`PlotLabel`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabel.html) and then it works. Like so:

```
$Version
```

> `12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)`

We begin

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
```

and then

```
myplot = ListLogLogPlot[{{}, {}, {}}, 
  PlotRange -> 10^{{1, 4}, {-10, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Blue, Orange}, Frame -> True, Joined -> False, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.65, FrameStyle -> 15, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[15, Black], 
  FrameLabel -> {{Style["", Italic, 18], 
     Style["", 18]}, {Style["", 18], None}}, 
  Filling -> {4 -> {Top, Directive[Brown, Opacity[0.8]]}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> {Placed[
     LineLegend[{Style["Case A", 12], Style["Case B", 12], 
       Style["Case C", 12]}, 
      LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}], 
        Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}], 
        Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 3}]}]}, 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5, 
          Background -> White] &), 
      LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}], {0.75, 0.15}]}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[StringForm["Parameter X = `` and Parameter Y = ``", 1, 2], 
    Black, 17]]
```

Finally,

```
Export["Plot.png", myplot, ImageResolution -> 500];
```

> [image: plot]